# How to achieve the bucket values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms-2012

I have schedule table like this *(table name = testSch)*

```
ID  Amount  scheduleDate     
1   7230.00  2018-07-13  
1   7272.00  2018-07-27  
1   7314.00  2018-08-10  
1   7356.00  2018-08-24  
1   7398.00  2018-09-07  
1   7441.00  2018-09-21  
1   7439.00  2018-10-08  
1   7526.00  2018-10-22  
1   7570.00  2018-11-05  
1   7613.00  2018-11-19  
1   5756.00  2018-12-03
```

I need to sum the *Amount* field based on specific bucket values as shown below

- Principal_7To30_Days
- Principal_1To3_Months
- Principal_3To6_Months
- Principal_6To12_Months
- Principal_1To3_Years

by giving an input date

And my input date is *2018-07-09* and below is my query;

```
;with cteSchedule as (
select *,DATEDIFF(DAY,'20180709',scheduleDate) as datedifference, 
DATEDIFF(MONTH,'20180709',scheduleDate) as monthdifference from testSch)
select  ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.datedifference <7),0)  AS Principal_0To7_Days, 

    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.datedifference>=7 and cteSchedule.datedifference<30),0)  
    AS Principal_7To30_Days,

    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.datedifference>=30 and cteSchedule.datedifference<90),0)  AS Principal_1To3_Months,

    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.datedifference>=90 and cteSchedule.datedifference<180),0)  AS Principal_3To6_Months,

    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.datedifference>=180 and cteSchedule.datedifference<365),0)  AS Principal_6To12_Months
```

And below is my output

```
Principal_0To7_Days Principal_7To30_Days    Principal_1To3_Months Principal_3To6_Months Principal_6To12_Months  
7230.00             7272.00                 29509.00              35904.00       0.00
```

But the correct output should be

```
    Principal_0To7_Days Principal_7To30_Days    Principal_1To3_Months Principal_3To6_Months Principal_6To12_Months  
7230.00             7272.00                     36948.00              28465.00       0.00
```

So the problem is i'm getting wrong values for *Principal_1To3_Months* and *Principal_3To6_Months*, When I asked my client how do they calculate this in their legacy system, they replied that they calculate using +-months by adding number of months and not days. So if today is  2018-07-09 + 3 months we will get  2018-10-09.

So I used the month difference in my cte query as below

```
 DATEDIFF(MONTH,'20180709',scheduleDate) as monthdifference
```

And use this in my overall query as below

```
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cteSchedule.Amount) 
    FROM cteSchedule 
    WHERE cteSchedule.monthdifference>=1 and cteSchedule.monthdifference<=3),0)  AS Principal_1To3_Months
```

But this time also I get the same values as mentioned in my very first output.
Can someone please point out where is my mistake and how to achieve this values as mentioned in correct output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `DATEDIFF` to calculation `day` or `month` difference days, because there is some month have 31 days, others month have 30 days.

Therefore, the calculated difference days are not accurate.

I would use `DATEADD` instead of `DATEDIFF` to do the condition.

```
;with cteSchedule as (
select *,'20180709' compareDay
from testSch
)
SELECT Sum(CASE 
            WHEN t.scheduleDate < DATEADD(day, 7, compareDay) 
            THEN t.amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS  Principal_0To7_Days,
        Sum(CASE 
            WHEN t.scheduleDate >=DATEADD(day, 7, compareDay) AND t.scheduleDate < DATEADD(day, 30, compareDay) 
            THEN t.amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Principal_7To30_Days,
        Sum(CASE 
            WHEN t.scheduleDate >=DATEADD(month,1,compareDay) AND t.scheduleDate < DATEADD(month,3,compareDay)
            THEN t.amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Principal_1To3_Months,
        Sum(CASE 
            WHEN  t.scheduleDate >=DATEADD(month,3,compareDay) AND t.scheduleDate < DATEADD(month,6,compareDay)
            THEN t.amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Principal_3To6_Months,
        Sum(CASE 
            WHEN t.scheduleDate >=DATEADD(month,6,compareDay) AND t.scheduleDate < DATEADD(month,12,compareDay)
            THEN t.amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Principal_6To12_Months
from cteSchedule t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0444/17)

**[Results]**:

```
| Principal_0To7_Days | Principal_7To30_Days | Principal_1To3_Months | Principal_3To6_Months | Principal_6To12_Months |
|---------------------|----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|                7230 |                 7272 |                 36948 |                 28465 |                      0 |
```

**Note**

You can use `CASE WHEN` with `SUM` 
*Aggregate function* instead of `select` subquery, the performance will be better.

Comment: @Mar1009 No problem glad to help :)